# How to convert a MySQL BLOB into a PHP array of shorts?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, blob, converters

I'm making a game and I plan on using the MySQL BLOB for the character inventory as it seems faster than

```
CREATE TABLE inventory
(
    userid INT,
    itemid SMALLINT
);
```

as it will be in one place.

The only problem is how? How do I convert an array of interger, I only need to bytes, to a php image for the database and vice-versa.

Comment: Don't. It may seem faster at first glance, but everytime you need to change an item you'll have to pull the blob, convert it, search the item, change it, convert the array again, store it again in the database. all operations the DB can do better than PHP. Just use a table for it.

Comment: True, but I plan on having it deBLOBed everytime the user logs on and the resulting array stay in memory until the user logs off. Then the array will be BLOBified and stored in the database.

Comment: Do. Not. Do. This. How pulling a byte stream that represents an array of integers, could be faster than pulling an array of integers?

Answer (score 0):

To quote the comments: ***do not do this***. What you're essentially saying is *'hey I have this wonderful thing called a Relational Database Management System, capable of storing huge amounts of organized data, and I'm going to just use it as a fricking flat file system, because who needs organization and structure in their data?'*.

Then why bother with a database at all? Just make a folder on the filesystem called `inventory` and store a ton of JSON files in there for every user. I guarantee you that any local filesystem with proper caching mechanics will vastly outperform a networked database system if performance is that important to you.

In reality, your real problem is [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), summarized as:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying
>   about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these
>   attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when
>   debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: **premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil**. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that
>   critical 3%.

Just write your game, and don't worry about performance too much. When you notice that it's becoming a problem, find out where and fix that. It's highly unlikely that it's going to be in a 2-field database table.